# Advertise over Web Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

Is it possible to advertise a service as a website using web Bluetooth?

I have a progressive web app and want to communicate over Bluetooth with another instance of the web app.

I have not found any indication in the [web Bluetooth documentation](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/) that it is possible but also that it is not.

Currently, only Bluetooth LE (Low Energy) is supported over the web. [Also see implementation status](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Bluetooth Web Javascript APIs only support Central role, means we can only scan for advertisers.
Peripheral role is not yet support till Bluetooth 5.2 version for Web APIs. 
Find some information here, https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-resources/intro-to-web-bluetooth/

Hope this helps!